# js promise - how to end "then" execution if a condition is fulfilled and continue to next then if not

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a promise with 1 `.then()` method which I would like to divide in smaller pieces (because it is to long...).

it looks similar to this (simplified) example:

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(false);
  }, 500);
});

myPromise
  .then(value => {
    if (value) {
      // do something
      console.log('value: ' + value)
      console.log('do something');
    } else {
      // do something else only if value=true
      // this is really long.............
      console.log('value: ' + value)
      console.log('do something else');
    }
  });
```

to simplify I thought of doing something like this:

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(false);
  }, 500);
});

myPromise
  .then(value => {
    if (value) {
      // do something
      console.log('value: ' + value)
      console.log('do something');
      // stop "then" execution (next "then" should not run) -> HOW TO DO THIS?
    } else {
      // continue processing in next then
      return value
    }
  })
  .then(value => {
    // do something else only if value=false
    console.log('value: ' + value)
    console.log('do something else');
  })
```

what I am unable to figure out is how to get `// stop "then" execution (next "then" should not run) -> HOW TO DO THIS?` to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "stop" `then` chains by returning a **rejected** promise, this why it will "jump" to `catch` phase.

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(true);
  }, 500);
});

myPromise
  .then(value => {
    if (value) {
      // do something
      console.log('value: ' + value);
      console.log('do something');
      // stop "then" execution (next "then" should not run) -> HOW TO DO THIS?
      return Promise.reject();
    } else {
      // continue processing in next then
      return value;
    }
  })
  .then(value => {
    // do something else only if value=false
    console.log('value: ' + value);
    console.log('do something else');
  });
```

Comment: and will throw an error. I would have to handle "good errors" there. correct? _note: I use the `catch()` method to handle errors_

Comment: yes, you'll need some logic in your `catch`